# GPS Checker on Android not launching Dialog

Tags: android, error-handling, gps

So I understand how to launch the GPS window on Android if the GPS is not enabled however in my case the code is not launching (despite the fact that all the other gps features in my class are working perfectly) I am doing the following:

```
    // CHECK GPS!
    gps = new gpstracker(MainActivity.this);
    if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
    } else {
        final ComponentName toLaunch = new ComponentName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.SecuritySettings");
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);

            }
```

When I ran the following outside of the if statement it worked fine:

```
        final ComponentName toLaunch = new ComponentName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.SecuritySettings");
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
```

I am just at a loss as to why the gps knows it can't get a location but fails to trigger the else part of the statement. I have attached the GPS class I am using.

gps class
https://gist.github.com/4416280

Comment: Did you double check that `gps.canGetLocation()` actually returns false so that the `else` portion is executed?

Comment: I will check that now I have this working in a bigger setup but I shorted it hear but I'll just add a toast/log to see if anything comes back.

Comment: Checked in my larger loop with the same test, and it believes the GPS is enabled, it must be that it thinks when the wifi is on (which it is) and the GPS is off that the GPS is positive for being enabled.

Comment: So you've got other logic issues to fix :)

Comment: That's the problem if I can get any signal - wifi, network or GPS it thinks it is enabled. Is there a way to state that it's not if it can't find both a network and WiFi?

Comment: Yup, thanks, will look into the class file.

Comment: Looks like this was the solution in the class (interestingly enough a lot of the SO questions have this problem):

   if (!isGPSEnabled || !isNetworkEnabled) {
    // no network provider is enabled
    this.canGetLocation = false;

Comment: According to that, if there is a gps connection, but there is not a network connection, you return false. The gps by itself can get a connection, but slowly.